# How to push to History in React Router v6? I face with not found message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I used `react@18`, `redux`, and `react-router@6`. I have a button add to cart on my product page and I want the product to be added to local storage and I have that product on my Cart page. After clicking on add to cart button I passed to Cart page with id but it shows not found. How can I solve this problem?

app.js :

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" index element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
    <Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartPage />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

cartAction.js

```
export const addToCart = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(http://localhost:8000/products/${id});
  dispatch({
    type: "CART_ADD_ITEM",
    payload: {
      id: data.id,
      title: data.title,
      image1: data.image1,
      price: data.price,
    },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

store.js

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: ProductListReducer,
  productDetail: ProductDetailReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

const cartItemsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];
const initialState = { cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromLocalStorage } };
const middleWare = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(...middleWare)
);
```

cartReducer.js

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CART_ADD_ITEM":
      const item = action.payload;
      const existingItems = state.cartItems.find(
        (i) => i.id === item.id
      );
      if (existingItems) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
            i.id === existingItems.id ? item : i
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

cart page:

```
const CartPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  console.log(cartItems);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(addToCart(id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  const removeCartHandler= (id) => {
    dispatch(removeCart(id))
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col lg="12">
          <h1>basket</h1>

          {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
            <p className="text-center">there is nothing in the basket</p>
          ) : (
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              {cartItems.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item.id}>
                    <CartItems product={item} remove={()=>removeCartHandler(item.id)}/>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                );
              })}
            </ListGroup>
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

cart Items

```
const CartItems = ({product}) => {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={2}>
        <Image src={product.image1} alt={product.title} fluid />
      </Col>
      <Col md={3}>{product.title}</Col>
      <Col md={2}>{product.price}</Col>
    </Row>
```

product page

```
const { id } = useParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const addToCartHandler = () => {
  navigate(/cart/${id});
};

<Button className="btn btn-default" onClick={addToCartHandler}>
  <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing `"?"` from the cart path. `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components don't take optional parameter or use regular expressions in the `path` prop.

Change `path="/cart/:id?"` to `path="/cart/:id"`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
    <Route path="/cart/:id" element={<CartPage />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you. it shows my cart page but my state is empty and do not show the product was added. why?

Comment: @ElhamBagheri That question is a bit off-topic from the question of this post regarding the navigation. If I'm reading the code correctly though it seems you navigate from the `ProductPage` page via the button click and `navigate` function, and the `CartPage` component is trying to take the `id` path param and dispatch `addToCart(id)` to the store to add an item. Is this correct? `CartPage` isn't passed any props, so `match` is undefined. Are you sure `const id = match.params.id` isn't throwing an error in the `CartPage` component code? Is the `addToCart` action dispatched?

Comment: yes, it is correct. and  const id = match.params.id throw an error and match is undefined and I remove match as a props and changed   const { id } = useParams();. now it shows the items in console and after I add 2 product it shows 2 rows but it doesn't show the image or name and price. yes, addToCart is dispatched.

Comment: @ElhamBagheri Do you have the Redux devtools and extension installed in your browser so you can explore the Redux state? Is the `state.cart.cartItems` array updated as expected? `CartItems` appears to not correctly access `product` from the props object. In fact, it named the props object `product`, so if you want to access the `product` prop you should access it as `product.product`... or just name the props object `props` like normal, or don't name it and destructure `product`.

Comment: well, my problem was I forgot to write {} before and after product on cartItems.js  in the const CartItems = (product). I should write const CartItems = ({product}). thank you very much for your help. have a wonderful day.